# Form button keeps showing results in new window

Tags: javascript, html

Very new to html and javascript here.  I get the following form up and it calculates correctly but the result shows up in a new page.  I'd like it to stay in the same page.  Not sure what I did wrong here.  Also, is there any way to shorten the function? Seems like a lot of work to do a simple calculation.  Any help would be great.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Help!</help>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function add(x,y){
        var x = document.add1.add2.value;
        var y = document.add1.add3.value;
        var x = Number(x);
        var y = Number(y);
        var z = x+y;
        return (z);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Help me stack overflow you're my only hope!</h3>

    <form name="add1">
    Input first number to add: <input type="number" name="add2">
    2nd number: <input type="number" name="add3">
    <input type="button" value="Result"
    onclick = "document.write('The total is: ' + add() + '.');" />

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont' use [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) to display data, it overwrites entire document. You don't want that. It's better to create new function which would render result into some other element:

```
<input type="button" value="Result" onclick="showResult('The total is: ' + add() + '.');" />
```

and the showResult function can be for example:

```
function showResult(result) {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7ujzn35c/

Here are also a couple of general improvements you can make your code:

1. move string manupulations to showResult completely:

   ```
   <input type="button" value="Result" onclick="showResult()" />
   ```

   http://jsfiddle.net/7ujzn35c/1/
2. call `add` from inside `showResults`

   ```
   onclick="showResult(this.form.add2.value, this.form.add3.value)"
   ```

   http://jsfiddle.net/7ujzn35c/2/

Comment: please re-write his adding function! haha! upvote none-the-less

Comment: @Phil I know, just didn't want to change too much. I will add one more example.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <title>Help!</help>
```

First of all, This should be `<title> Help! </title>`

Secondly, document.write function actually starts writing the entire page anew.

You should either  `replace onclick = "document.write('The total is: ' + add() + '.');"`  with

```
onclick = "alert('The total is: ' + add() + '.');"
```

Better still, you could create a div element like so

```
<title> Help! </title>

<script>
.....
</script>

</header>

<body>

<div id = 'output'> </div> ...
```

then

```
 `onclick = "document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =  'The total is: ' + add() + '.';"
```

And don't give up. Hope this helps you